# Path distance tool only downhill using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, path, accumulated

I'm working on a protection forest model against avalanches and rockfall processes and I have a problem with the path distance tool. I want to calculate the accumulated costs of rockfs travelling DOWNHILL from source cells which represent cliffs.
My cost raster looks like this for not forested terrain and like this for forested terrain:

```
Slope:          not forested Values:        forested Values:
0 -5 °          10              30  
5 - 10°         9               27  
10- 15°         8               24
.......         ...             ...
45° and steeper     1           3
```

If the accumulated path from the start cells is about a certain threshold it will be unlikely that the rockfall process will reach further than this.

How can I use the path distance tool to only calculate the pathdistance for areas downslope from a source cell?

How is it possible to stop the process when it goes uphill again?

For example if process hits valleybottom and opposite slope.

Comment: Flow direction from hydrology toolset (fill first), flow accumulation using your cost as weight raster.